# Long vector error when running Random Forest on small dataframe

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to run a RandomForest on a dataset with 390343 rows in R with the randomForest package.I am getting this error :

Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  long vectors (argument 24) are not supported in .Fortran

As my number of rows is very small comapred to 2^31, I am unable to figure out the cause of the error.

The summary of the data being used is :

```
summary(train1)
```

[image: training data summary]

I am running this on R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) on a 64 bit Windows server 2012 with 128 GB RAM and a Intel Xeon CPU(E5-2690 v2)

The command used to run the RF is

```
RFmod<-randomForest(Train_flag~., data=train1,ntree=3000,
                mtry=4,replace=TRUE,keep.forest=TRUE,importance=TRUE)
```

Comment: Update : The issue was with the proximity matrix randomForest calculates, it's size comes out to be (4*10^5)^2 which comes out to be greater than 2^31, changing the proximity argument to FALSE is working

Answer (score 1):

Try using `proximity = FALSE`. When this parameter is set to `TRUE`, the algorithm computes the proximity matrix, which can be an issue when the dataframes are too big.

Answer (score 0):

The limit to the number of rows in a `randomForest` calculation most likely is not `2^31`, but will likely be hit way before that when you run out of memory.  I'm not familiar with the exact error message you are getting, but the workaround to this is simple.  Don't train a random forest model on 400K observations.  Instead, take a reasonably-sized subset, say 20K observations, and train on this instead.  You most likely can capture the behavior of the 400K set with a carefully chosen subset.